# LoadableComponent support in python selenium package

Tags: python

Does anyone know if the python selenium package supports LoadableComponent?  I want to avoid explicitly checking if a page is loaded. Looking for LoadableComponent support in python

Answer (score 0):

I openly admit I don't know everything. That said, here's my best answer for you so far...

The Python bindings for Selenium do not really have a 1-to-1 equivalent with `LoadableComponent<T>` as you may know it from Java or C#. To my knowledge, there is no factory in Python Selenium that will allow a class/instance variable of `WebElement` to be automatically loaded, which is what `LoadableComponent<T>` takes care of for you. This may be partially due to the fact that `@decorators` in Python are not equivalent to `@Annotations` in Java nor `[Attributes]` in C#. Python `@decorators` as of 3.4 may only be applied to functions and classes, not variables.

You may still manually implement the Page Object Design Pattern... it just won't look quite the same as C# or Java and will be a bit more of a "from scratch" approach.

You can use the source by looking here: [Python Selenium Source](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/#git/py/selenium/webdriver/remote)

If you find out how to do this better than I have just explained or if I'm wrong and you have the answer, then please do let me know. :-) I was thinking about this very problem, which is how I found your question. Perhaps in the future there will be a more Pythonic way if there isn't one already. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've make my own implementation. For now load and is_loaded little bit useless

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class LoadableComponent(ABC):

    def __init__(self, driver: WebDriver, page: str):
        self.driver = driver
        self.page = page

        driver.get(page)

    @abstractmethod
    def load(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def is_loaded(self):
        pass
```